# Connecting to Oracle database from SSIS or SSMS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ssms, linked-server

I want to connect to an oracle db by linked server method on the SSMS (v 17) or SSIS if the first one doesn't work.  I've installed oracle 12c, added the paths properly. But in SSMS, I cannot see the provider for Oracle in the providers list.

I want to know how I can achieve this connection between oracle and an sql server. Do I miss anything in the setup/config?

Comment: Did you install the OLE DB provider? Is the Oracle Client the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) as your SSIS?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Does this provider included in when we install Oracle 12 c ? Otherwise I think I didn't.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "when we install Oracle 12c". There are many versions. By default the Oracle Instant Client does not include the OLE DB provider.

Comment: Follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server